# Appending Content To A Div, Then Trying To Slidedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, append, slidedown

I have a validation script that once submitted, will append error "li" tags to an empty div below the form. It works great though I would like to slide down this div once the "li" tags are appended to the div.

I have used the .slideDown effect from jQuery to accomplished this but it seems to only slide down to the first "li" tag, after that it jumps through the rest of the "li" tags. I can't figure out why, and the slide down effect is on the div itself not the "li" tags.

Here is a working example in my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jbatzel1Development/pen/twdlu).

Here is the code:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  $("li").remove();

  $("input").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($($this).val() === ""){
      var formName      = $($this).attr("name");
      var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
      var li            = $("<li></li>",{
        text: "There was an error with " + formName,
        class: "errorText",
      });

      $($this).addClass("errorInput");
      $(errorMessage).append(li);
      $(errorMessage).slideDown(1500);
      e.preventDefault();
    } if($($this).val() != ""){
      $($this).removeClass("errorInput"); 
    } else{
      return true; 
    }
  }); //Input
}); //Form .submit
```

Comment: Not the issue, but you're double wrapping your `$this` variable in jquery.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I did that haha.

Comment: the error msg `div` gets shown when looping through the first `li`, then you append another `li` on the second iteration

Answer (score 3):

Remove the slidedown from the each() function and place it after the loop, it is been called twice.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nxtFi

Hope it helps.

Comment: Use your `has_error` variable to check whether or not it needs to slide to avoid some flicker before form submit.

Comment: hack.augusto, thanks that does make sense! Jack thank you as well, I was wondering what has-error was.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `.slideDown()` inside the `.each()`, so it's being called once for each of your input elements. However, I suspect `.slideDown()` only animates if the element it's being called on isn't currently visible.

So, you add one `<li>`, call `.slideDown()`, and it animates. You add the next `<li>`, call `.slideDown()`, and nothing happens because it's already visible; however, since you've added content to the container element, it grows in size (the "jumping" you mentioned).

Simply call this line:

```
$(errorMessage).slideDown(1500);
```

after the entire call to `.each()`.